# Constant size global arrays in C

Tags: c, gdb

I'm trying to figure out there best way to define a global array with a constant size and I've come to the following options, all with their own flaws.

```
// 1:
#define ASIZE 10
int array[ASIZE];

// 2:
enum {ASIZE = 10};
int array[ASIZE];

// 3:
#define ASIZE_DEF 10
static const int ASIZE = ASIZE_DEF;
int array[ASIZE_DEF];
```

The problem with the first two is that I can't get the value of `ASIZE` from GDB. I guess the third option is best because I can still dump the value of the `const`, but it also leaks in another macro. I can `undef` the macro after defining the array and `const` but if the `#define` and the `const` are in a separate file from the array declaration, then it gets a bit hairy.

Is there a better way?

Comment: what is number 3 supposed to do? The `static` variable would only bring you "unused variable" warnings, no?

Comment: @JensGustedt GCC doesn't complain

Comment: @JensGustedt Actually, 'static' in C means local to the compilation unit (= module = object file). It is the opposite of 'extern'.    

As 'static' is default for variables ('extern' is default for functions), explicitly stating a variable as 'static' changes nothing, but it can be nice semantical addition for programmer who reads the code.    
    
Note that declaring symbol 'static' means the compiler can actually check, if it is ever used, since it sees the entire scope of symbol's lifetime. Thus "unused *" warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dealing with a GDB issue, not a C issue. You can also do #4, which is arguably better than #3.

```
enum {ASIZE = 10};
static const int ASIZE_FOR_GDB = ASIZE;
int array[ASIZE];
```

Answer (score 8):

Doing something for the sake of the debugger is wrong. Incidentally, [gdb knows about this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html#Macros) if you [compile your code right](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compilation.html#Compilation).

> Some languages, such as C and C++, provide a way to define and invoke
>   “preprocessor macros” which expand into strings of tokens. gdb can
>   evaluate expressions containing macro invocations, show the result of
>   macro expansion, and show a macro's definition, including where it was
>   defined.
>
> Version 3.1 and later of gcc, the gnu C compiler, provides macro
>   information if you specify the options `-gdwarf-2` and `-g3`; the former
>   option requests debugging information in the Dwarf 2 format, and the
>   latter requests “extra information”.

Comment: I just tried this and was not able to get the preprocessor macros in gdb. Can you demonstrate how?

Comment: I looked and this doesn't seem to work on OS X. It may be a gcc/gdb issue.

Comment: @dschatz What `gcc` is that ? Does it complain about `-g3` et al ?

Comment: Having a symbol can be more than for the debugger. It also supports upgradability in dynamic libraries (since the constant is not compiled into client programs) and FFI from non-C languages.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that you are defining a constant, using it later to size one or more arrays, and also want that constant to be a symbol, preferably without a messy namespace. (If it were a matter of exporting the size of a single array, I would instead suggest `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)` as missingno did.)

```
static const int ASIZE = 10;
#define ASIZE            10
int array[ASIZE];
```

Here, there is a variable with the desired value which will be in the object file, but the preprocessor macro shadows it with the value itself, so the array definition also succeeds.

However, you may find the need to duplicate the value expression ugly. Wouldn't it be nice if we could define the variable in terms of the macro?

```
static const int ASIZE =
#define ASIZE 10
                         ASIZE;
int array[ASIZE];
```

I'm not sure whether this is actually a better idea maintainability-wise than the above, but it works (and I couldn't get gcc to be offended by it) and it contains no duplication other than of the identifier. And it's amusing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know `array` is a global array (and not just a pointer) you can find its length using

```
sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)
```

without needing to set an extra variable for that.

Comment: I don't find this particularly applicable. What if I define my array to be the size of an arithmetic expression of some constants? What I'm getting at is that I want the value of the constants, the point regarding the array is just that I can't have a const alone.

Comment: the sizeof method should still work if the array size is defined by a constant expression. Its true that doesn't shouw the value of the constants but it would be enough if you only cared for the length in the first place.

Comment: My point is that the array size is not the issue here, it is purely the constant value(s). I only make my case regarding a global array because then I am prevented from using just a single const which would be ideal otherwise.